# Programmatically compose object Id Name on Xamarin with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

I need to pass to a function an `ImageButton` but the ID depends on the pressed key (ex. if the user presses the 'x' key, I need to pass the 'Button_x' because I have to change the source image of the button).

```
string IDButton = "Button_key" + letter.ToString().ToUpper();  //ex. Button_keyX
ImageButton btn = new ImageButton();
btn.Id = IDButton;
function_that_changes_button_image_source(btn);
```

The problem is that the 'Id' is read-only.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: use the `ClassId` property

Comment: Does not work for me btn.ClassId = IDButton;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved, thanks to all.

I've used `this.ViewControls.FindByName(IDButton)`

```
private void myFunc()
{
    string IDButton = "Button_key" + letter.ToString().ToUpper();   //ex: Button_keyP if letter value is 'p'
    object btn = this.ViewControls.FindByName(IDButton) as object;

    function_that_changes_button_image_source(letter.ToString().ToLower(), btn);
    ...
}

 private void PutTheXon(string letter, object bottone)
{
    
    ImageButton btn2change = (ImageButton)bottone;
    btn2change.IsEnabled = false;
    btn2change.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("x_" + letter.ToLower() + "_pb.png");  //changes the source image 'x_p_pb.png' if letter value is 'p'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `function_that_changes_button_image_source` should accept just the id and not the whole button object.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to set the ```Id``` programmatically. For example: if I press 'x' on the keyboard, I need that the 'ImageButton' with  ```x:Name="Button_keyX"``` changes his source image

Comment: The function that changes the image should find the control with id/name Button_keyX and change the source image.

Comment: I've solved using ```this.ViewControls.FindByName```